# if all images select - Image Picker Plugin jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am using image picker plugin to select images. 
https://rvera.github.io/image-picker/

I have a small question. How can I write a statement to say that id all images selected than do something.

I will have a submit button. If all images are selected I will want button to show, otherwise hide.

**HTML**

```
<select class="image-picker" multiple="multiple" id="freestanding-sings-selection" name="freestanding-sings-selection" >
  <option class="process-icons" data-img-src='../../css/freestanding-signs/insert-fts.png' value="1" id="insert">
  </option>
  <option class="process-icons insert_cover" data-img-src="../../css/freestanding-signs/cover-fts.png" value="2">
  </option>
  <option class="" data-img-src="../../css/freestanding-signs/label.png" value="3">
  </option>
</select>
```

**JavaScript**

```
$("#freestanding-sings-selection").imagepicker({
  //if all images slected {
    //do something
  //}
});
```

Thank you

**Edit Self made check**

```
$("#freestanding-sings-selection").imagepicker({
  selected: function(selected) { 
    if (selected.length >= 3) {
      alert(3);
    }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you read the documentation of the Image Picker you see that the plugin implemented a few callbacks; changed, clicked, selected. Callbacks are triggered when you perform certain actions like clicking an image, of changing the selected images.

So do something like this:

```
$("#freestanding-sings-selection").imagepicker({
    selected: function() { 
        if (document.querySelectorAll('.selected').length > 3) {
            // do something
        }
    }
})
```

this is an example with the `selected` trigger, determine which one you really need

I used document.querySelectorAll('.selected') because the demopage of the Image Picker shows that selected images get the selected class. So its possible to simple count them and add them to your businesslogic

Comment: This works but, I want to say if all images are selected than run the function. The above code will trigger the functions every time i click an image.

Comment: Use the "limit_reached" callback. If you have set the limit to 2, and you have selected 2, the callback is triggered

Comment: I tried limit_reached. I have 3 images and If I limit to 2; user will not be able to select 3 image. And if i set the limit to 3, nothing get triggered because it would get triggered if there was 4th image and user click the 4th image.

Comment: is it possible to use the selected trigger with a self made check to determine how many images are selected. So inside the selected callback something like if (selectedimages >= 3) { // do something }

Comment: No the self made check also didn't worked. I updated my original question.

Comment: Thank you Jasper. You solution works great. It check for if 3 images selected than do something. But I guess the code only get triggered when image is selected. If user un-select the image, the it doesn't detect it check for if statement. so for example if I select all 3 images, i see the alert. and if i un-select the one image, i don't see the alert as it doesn't trigger the select.

Comment: try instead of the selected trigger the change trigger. I guess an deselection will trigger that one

Comment: Yes. changed triggered worked. Thank you Jasper for you help. God bless you.